# How to reload certain web images, but not from cache, in Django application?

Tags: django, image, caching

My Django 1.62. application contains a "show_members" view/template that shows the names and
photos of all members on my site.  The catch is that I have to review each member's photo before allowing it to be displayed on the show_members page.  Therefore, when a new member joins, I display a placeholder image until I've reviewed and approved their photo.  Once that's done, their real photo should be displayed on that page.

Now currently I use the same name for both the placeholder image and the real photo.  This allows me to easily display either image on the show_members page with this HTML:

```
<!-- Part of show_members.html   placeholder and photo both named username_thumb.jpg -->
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}photos/approved/{{ username }}/{{ username }}_thumb.jpg" />
```

The problem is that when a new user first joins the site, the show_members template will show their placeholder image (from the server) plus the photos of other site members (usually from the client's browser cache) as it should.  However, once I've approved the new users photo, their old placeholder image will continue to appear in the client browser unless the client's user forces a refresh while bypassing their cache.

Is there a way I can programmatically force the show_templates page to repull the new user's new approved photo from the server while still retrieving the cached images for the other users?  I realize that I could give different names to the placeholder image and approved photo and then pass a boolean to the template and use it to display one or the other.  However, that seems like a rather inelegant solution.   Is there another customary way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if won't be better to use model function to display either their user_thumb_filename or a default placeholder image? So the image source would be something like `user.thumb.url`. This has its own issues, but seems better than saving a unique default image for every user.

Comment: What does "approving" the image entail?  Are you changing any database fields, or just overwriting the image, or ...

Comment: No information about my images and photos are kept in a database.  All logic assumes the files reside in certain named directories and have meaningful names based on the username.  When a photo is approved, I just replace the default image placeholder with the actual photo but each has the same name based on the username.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is simply put a query parameter after the image so that it will cause the cache to be reloaded :

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}photos/approved/{{ username }}/{{ username }}_thumb.jpg?v={{ username.updated_at }}" />
```

In this example I suppose you have an updated_at field which correspond to the datetime of the last update of you model.